# Scala Code snippet - What is the Java 8 equivalent?

Tags: java, scala

What is the Java equivalent of the following Scala code snippet?

```
val codeLength = 8
val value: Long = 12345678
("0" * codeLength + value.toString).takeRight(codeLength)
```

It is the third line I am particularly interested in knowing what the Java 8 equivalent is.

Comment: If you explain what this code does, you'll be able to get help from people who know Java but don't know Scala

Comment: @Eran, I was not sure what that line of code did specifically but it is part of a larger section of code which is used to generate TOTP Auth codes. This one line I wasn't sure of what it was doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a zero filler

```
String.format("%08d", value)
```

Mind should the long have more than 8 digits you get an overflow.

Comment: I think your answer gives me exaclty what I need in terms of the actual Java 8 equivalent. `value` I believe will never be longer than 8 digits so no overflow should ever occur.

Comment: in Scala, `f"$value%08d"`

Answer (score 2):

- `"0" * codeLength` appends eight zeroes to one another.
- after that `value.toString` is appended to the eight zeroes.
- `.takeRight(codeLength)` takes the last `codeLength` (in this case -
  8) characters from the resulting String. Which is `value.toString`.

So, I would guess that the Java equivalent would simply be:

```
String result = "12345678";
```

Comment: takeRight for the last 8.

Comment: In the Scala code `value` is a variable and NOT hardcoded to `"12345678"` (I should prob have mentioned that!). Your explanation makes it clear however that that line of code is used to fill in the value with zeroes in cases where `value` is shorter than `codeLength`.